# How to fix broken lines records of a file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In my csv file I'm getting data in incorrect format for a few rows, sometimes a line is broken into two lines as shown in below table. For EmpId 2, line is broken into two lines. How can I find such records and merge them into one line in correct format to fix the issue for such records using PowerShell. Expected output is shown in below table.

**Input File data:**

```
EmpId,EmpName,EmpLocation
1,"Jack","Austin"
2,"Pet
er","NYC"
3,"Raj","Delhi"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
EmpId,EmpName,EmpLocation
1,"Jack","Austin"
2,"Peter","NYC"
3,"Raj","Delhi"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a moment and take the [Tour] and read at least the help topic [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's helpful to know what you've already tried. Also it looks like you're new - the downvotes are just because the question probably won't be useful to a general audience. 
It will be helpful to have more context and scenarios. Some ideas: 
1.You could use a regex search to find line breaks between the " characters if the breaks are guaranteed to be in the middle of a string.
2. You could find any line that doesn't begin with an integer for the ID and concatenate it with the previous line (assuming the results don't have other non-string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My instinct was to do something similar to [Karthick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499424/4749264), however I first took a look at the output of `Import-Csv`.  Surprisingly it puts the line break in the individual property where it was found like:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\Broken.csv | fl 

EmpId       : 1
EmpName     : Jack
EmpLocation : Austin

EmpId       : 2
EmpName     : Pet
              er
EmpLocation : NYC

EmpId       : 3
EmpName     : Raj
EmpLocation : Delhi
```

Notice "peter" is broken across 2 lines.

So I saw some potential to bring the objects in and modify the underlying property values instead of trying to fix up the string data. I cooked up the below:

```
$CSVData = Import-Csv C:\temp\Broken.csv  

$CSVData | 
ForEach-Object{
    ForEach( $Property in $_.PSObject.Properties.Name )
    {
        $_.($Property) = $_.($Property) -replace "(`r|`n)"
    }
}

$CSVData

# If you want to re-export:
$CSVData | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\Fixed.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This code should work regardless of which field has the line break.

Comment: I don't think it is required to do a `if ...  -match` as that is already implied by the `replace`.

Comment: Holistic view Steven :) +1

Comment: @iRon Agreed.  I think that just got left in from the dev process.  At first I didn't realize there was a carriage return in there.  Long story, but at some point there was a `.split()` that I didn't want to do unnecessarily...  That said, if I'm going to do the `-match` might as well go straight to the `-replace`.  Assuming you don't mind I'll go ahead edit the answer.

Comment: @Steven Thanks, your code is more generic and can fix any field which has a line break. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below. This worked for me. I assumed the first line is the header.

```
$filepath = "D:\file.csv"
[string[]]$data = Get-Content $filepath

$data_Final = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

for($i = $j = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $(if($i -eq $j){$i++}else{$i=$j+1}), ($j=$i)) { 
    
    While ( ($data[$i] -split ",").Count -ne 3 ) {
        $j = $j+1
        # Concatenate the target line ($i) with successive line(s) ($j) until the elements Count to 3
        $data[$i] = $data[$i] + $data[$j]
    }

    $data_Final.Add($data[$i]) | Out-Null
    
}

$inputData = $data_Final | ConvertFrom-Csv
# Or, if you want to fix the csv uncomment the below
# $data_Final | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation
```